# Unionfs: deleting folder from upperdir results in diappearance of files in the overlayfs

Tags: linux, overlayfs

I've just found out that for overlayfs created with `sudo mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=iso,upperdir=to,workdir=temp overlay fin` when a file is modified in `fin` a file appears in upperdir along with folders to it (as expected). But what was unexpected that when I decided to revert changes and I deleted folder with the file in upperdir,  **corresponding folder in `fin` became empty**. One can just delete a file from upperdir (seems to work correctly), but why not OK to delete folders? Is it some specifics of overlayfs or maybe a bug on my system?

I had to remount `overlayfs` to fix it. Is there other way to revert that disappearance?